# Error in valid.viewpor: invalid 'yscale' in viewport

Tags: r, st

I have one month of data that I converted to STDFDF.

```
#set the spatial location of the regions
Data.loc <- data.frame(Stat = c("Firmo","Citta dei Ragazzi", "Rende",
                              "Schiavonea","Acri"),
                     ID = c("IT1766A", "IT1938A", "IT2086A",
                              "IT2090A", "IT2110A"),
                     Lat=c(39.71376, 39.3134, 39.33893,
                           39.65176, 39.48963),
                     Lon=c(16.19397, 16.24517, 16.24334,
                           16.54677, 16.3868))
coordinates(Data.loc) = ~Lon+Lat
proj4string(Data.loc) = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

stations = 4:8
Data.loc = Data.loc[match(names(combineData[stations]), Data.loc$Stat),]
Data.loc$Station = row.names(Data.loc)

combineData$time = ISOdate(combineData$Year, combineData$Month, combineData$Day, 0)

dataObj = STFDF(Data.loc, combineData$time, 
                data.frame(values = as.vector(t(combineData[stations]))))
```

Building a semivariogram does not give errors.

```
# 1. Empirical Semivariogram Creation
#Let’s try to calculate semivariogram with 150 Km cutoff and 20 width
var <- gstat::variogram(values ~ 1, # fixed effect component
                 data=dataObj,
                 width = 20, #spatial bin (20 km)
                 cutoff = 150, #consider pts < 150 km apart,
                 na.omit=T)
#tunit="days",assumeRegular=F

plot(var, ylab=bquote(gamma), xlab=c("h (separation distance in km)"))
plot(var, map = F)
plot(var, map = F, main = "Variogram", # with cutoff and fixed width
     xlab = "Separation distance (km)")
plot(var,wireframe=T)

# 2. Spatio-temporal Semivariogram Construction 
#### SEPARABLE MODEL ####
sepModel <- vgmST(stModel = "separable",
                space=vgm(0.9,"Exp", 50, 0.15), ##Factor,function,range,nugget
                time =vgm(0.9,"Exp", 3, 0.2),   ##Factor,function,range,nugget
                sill=20) # Base
sepFit <- fit.StVariogram(var, sepModel)

attr(sepFit,"optim.output")$value
#0.0002654625
#extractPar(sepFit)
#plot(var, sepFit, xlab = "distance (km)", map=F)

#### METRIC MODEL ####
metricModel <- vgmST(stModel = "metric",
                   joint = vgm(0.8, "Exp", 150, nugget = 0.2),
                   stAni = 100)

metricFit <- fit.StVariogram(var, metricModel)

#attr(metricFit,"optim.output")$value 0.0009653727
#extractPar(metricFit)
#plot(var, metricFit, xlab = "distance (km)", map=F)


#### COMPARE MODELS ####
attr(sepFit, "MSE")
attr(metricFit, "MSE")

## Best Fitted Model and Visualisation
sepMSE <- attr(sepFit, "optim")$value
metricMSE <- attr(metricFit, "optim")$value

plot(var, wireframe=T, scales=list(arrows=F, z = list(distance = 0.15)),
     xlab = "distance (km)", main='Emperical Model')
plot(var, sepFit, wireframe = T, scales=list(arrows=F, z = list(distance = 5)),
     main='Separable Model', xlab = "distance (km)")
plot(var, metricFit, wireframe=T, scales=list(arrows=F, z = list(distance = 5)),
     main='Metric Model', xlab = "distance (km)") 

plot(var, list(sepFit, metricFit), main = "Semi-variance")

plot(var,list(sepFit, metricFit),all=T,wireframe=T) 

# SPATIO-TEMPORAL Kriging Prediction
## Create space-time prediction grid
#-------------------------
spat_pred_grid <- expand.grid( lon = seq(36.5, 42.5, length = 100),
                               lat = seq(17.5, 22.5, length = 100)) %>%
  SpatialPoints(proj4string = CRS(proj4string(dataObj)))

gridded(spat_pred_grid) <- TRUE

class(spat_pred_grid)
## Create temporal grid based on the lag days
#-------------------
#temp_pred_grid <- as.POSIXct("2021-07-01 UGT") + seq(1, 31, length = 31)
temp_pred_grid <- seq(as.POSIXct("2021-07-01 00:00:00 UGT"),
                      as.POSIXct("2021-07-31 00:00:00 UGT"), length.out=31)
ST_pred <- STF(spat_pred_grid, temp_pred_grid)
# Kriging Prediction
#---------------------------
pred_kriged <- krigeST(values ~ 1,
                       data = dataObj, # data set
                       newdata = ST_pred, # prediction grid
                       modelList = sepFit, # best fitted semivariogram
                       computeVar = TRUE) # compute variances

#predSep <- krigeST(values~1, dataObj,
#                   STF(spat_pred_grid,temp_pred_grid),
#                   sepFit)

## Plot the Prediction Surface
#---------------------------
library(RColorBrewer)
color_pal <- rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral"))(16))
stplot(pred_kriged, xlab = "Latitude", ylab = "Longitude") 


#stplot(pred_kriged, sp.layout = cosenza, key.space = "right", cex = .5,
#       xlim = bbox(cosenza)[1,], ylim = bbox(cosenza)[2,])
## Plot the prediction standard error
#---------------------------
pred_kriged$se <- sqrt(pred_kriged$var1.var)

stplot(pred_kriged[, , "se"], main = "Prediction std. errors", 
       layout = c(6, 6), col.regions = color_pal)
```

I want to conduct space-time kriging, but I have the following problem in stplot:

```
Error in valid.viewport(x, y, width, height, just, gp, clip, mask, xscale,  : 
  invalid 'yscale' in viewport
```

I tried hundreds of coding options, but none of them solved my problem. I didn't find any information about this error.
Sample data:

```
structure(list(Year = c("2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021"), Month = c("07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
"07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
"07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
"07", "07", "07"), Day = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
"07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
"29", "30", "31"), `Citta dei Ragazzi` = c(51.79, 32.82, 22.54, 
16.66, 14.49, 14.12, 17.09, 20.14, 15.1, 14.8, 12.12, 13.26, 
16.59, 22.47, 17.7, 12.84, 8.57, 8.45, 10.33, 11.46, 13.83, 22.3, 
22.3, 17.8, 20.5883333333333, 18.7266666666667, 17.88, 18.1, 
18.3733333333333, 18.1966666666667, 19.525), Rende = c(28.82, 
12.3, 10.97, 9.3, 19.63, 15.72, 14.94, 17.07, 15.02, 9.61, 12.89, 
11.26, 16.76, 32.66, 10.75, 9.18, 9.43, 7.44, 12.12, 14.51, 14.76, 
16.48, 16.99, 17.16, 16.22, 24.68, 34.83, 37.66, 43.21, 43.75, 
36.16), Acri = c(28.3, 12.4, 14.3, 15.8, 19.4333333333333, 21.4333333333333, 
20, 21.7333333333333, 22.1, 15.8, 16.4, 15.1, 23.2, 37.2, 11.4, 
10.7, 8.8, 8.6, 13.3, 18.55, 17.1833333333333, 22.5333333333333, 
24.3666666666667, 22.8, 20.6, 26.8, 38.8, 46.3, 52.7, 50.4, 45.5
), Firmo = c(25.47, 17.88, 13.55, 14.98, 23.12, 16.8, 14.79, 
23.34, 20.45, 13.82, 18.35, 16.1, 31.37, 42.37, 15.17, 9.43, 
15.51, 12.85, 16.89, 17.01, 17.28, 20.48, 22.58, 25.03, 17.9771428571429, 
22.68, 16.1157142857143, 18.3342857142857, 19.3257142857143, 
55.7, 51.91), Schiavonea = c(35.41, 20.74, 15.29, 18.88, 19.26, 
20.09, 19.33, 35.28, 22.19, 18.09, 17.24, 20.26, 19.54, 38.88, 
15.16, 11.55, 10.61, 13.72, 11.98, 17.35, 29.52, 39.19, 31.67, 
28.16, 31.96, 29.68, 26.82, 42.89, 61.02, 60.04, 52.71), time = structure(c(1625097600, 
1625184000, 1625270400, 1625356800, 1625443200, 1625529600, 1625616000, 
1625702400, 1625788800, 1625875200, 1625961600, 1626048000, 1626134400, 
1626220800, 1626307200, 1626393600, 1626480000, 1626566400, 1626652800, 
1626739200, 1626825600, 1626912000, 1626998400, 1627084800, 1627171200, 
1627257600, 1627344000, 1627430400, 1627516800, 1627603200, 1627689600
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), row.names = c(NA, 
-31L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Going to be hard to help just based on an error message. Does it do this in every case or just one data set? Can you include your code and if possible some data? Can you list the packages you are using and ideally make a fully reproducible example?

Comment: I include my code. 
Libraries:
library(gstat)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(latticeExtra)
library(spacetime)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)

Comment: You've missed out how you create `sepVgm`. I can run your code up to the point where `krigeST` is called which needs `sepVgm`.

Comment: Sorry. I add sepVgm.

Comment: I get an error at `plot(var, wireframe=T)`: "`Error in units == units[1L] : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented`" but skipping (since its just a plot) that I then get `sepFit <- fit.StVariogram(var, sepModel)` giving "`Error in vgm(1 - par[4], as.character(model$time$model[2]), par[3], par[4],  : 
  range should be positive`". Not sure if those errors are related but I can't get past the second one.

Comment: I don't get this error

Comment: Are you using that same sample data as `combineData` or an extended data set? Is there some way you can dump your final `kriged_pred` object that breaks `stplot` as a binary R data object on a share we can work with? `save(kriged_pred,"kp.RData")` and then put on a shared dropbox or other file sharing system?

Comment: Of course, an extended data set. I updated R today and now I have the same error you wrote above.

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u51ciif27kowikl/kp.RData?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

In your saved `.RData` file the prediction grid is 310,000 identical values:

```
> summary(pred_kriged@data)
   var1.pred        var1.var     
 Min.   :3.131   Min.   :0.3089  
 1st Qu.:3.131   1st Qu.:0.3089  
 Median :3.131   Median :0.3089  
 Mean   :3.131   Mean   :0.3089  
 3rd Qu.:3.131   3rd Qu.:0.3089  
 Max.   :3.131   Max.   :0.3089
```

Such a flat surface may trouble plotting code that is trying to scale it to a range for a colour palette.

If I simply replace those values with some random noise, then `stplot` works fine, confirming my hypothesis:

```
> pred_kriged@data$var1.pred=runif(310000)
> pred_kriged@data$var1.var=runif(310000)
> stplot(pred_kriged)
# a noisy plot appears
```

So the question is "why is my predicted surface so flat?". This could be an error in the code (which we are struggling to reproduce...) or maybe your input data is flat, or near flat, or the variance is making it flat. Hard to tell without a working reproducible example, but the root reason for the error in `stplot` is... your data are flat...

Comment: This is sample data for 1 month
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/go8ix13gfbbzs8t/data.RData?dl=0)
I save my final pred_kriged object when I use the METRIC MODEL
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u51ciif27kowikl/kp.RData?dl=0)
In this case i have no error, but I want to extract data for other unknown points (long, lat) before kriging for the same period and build a prediction surface using a shapefile. Вo you know how to implement it?

Comment: In your opinion, how should this situation be handled?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what the question is now. The original error, as in the title of the question, "Error in valid.viewpor: invalid 'yscale' in viewport" is caused by trying to map a flat surface. I don't think we've reproduced why you have a flat surface and that might require a new question where a simple reproducible example could be made.